# Return a number of how many times an attribute has been used in XML using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<CITY>
<STREET>
<HOUSE>
<FLAT>
<INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="M">John Doe</INHABITANT>
<INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="F">Jane Doe</INHABITANT>
<INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="M">John Doe</INHABITANT>
</FLAT>
</HOUSE>
</STREET>
</CITY>
```

Using XQuery I need to return this:

```
<GENDERS><FEMALES>1</FEMALES><MALES>2</MALES></GENDERS>
```

How would I go about doing this?
What would the code be for this?
As I understand XQuery is for XML what SQL is for databases, so that kind of gives me an idea. This is for a school project that requires XQuery and I have 0 experience with this.

Comment: What software you are using for your task? SQL Server (SQL and XQuery), BaseX (XQuery), or anything else?

Comment: XQuery and XML file

Comment: http://xpatheval.apphb.com/

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, good news is I wrote the code needed for this. Im gonna mark this as fixed when I get my 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is as follows:

```
let $doc := document {
   <CITY>
    <STREET>
      <HOUSE>
        <FLAT>
          <INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="M">John Doe</INHABITANT>
          <INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="F">Jane Doe</INHABITANT>
          <INHABITANT Year="1990" Gender="M">John Doe</INHABITANT>
        </FLAT>
      </HOUSE>
    </STREET>
  </CITY>
}
return element GENDERS {
  let $genders := $doc//INHABITANT/@Gender
  return (
    element FEMALES { count($genders[. = 'F']) },
    element MALES   { count($genders[. = 'M']) }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers I got in this post, I've made this code which works exactly as needed. Thanks to everyone who chimed in (Christian Grūn)

```
let $male:=//INHABITANT[@Gender="M"]
let $female:=//INHABITANT[@Gender="F"]
return 
<GENDERS>
<FEMALES>{count($female)}</FEMALES>
<MALES>{count($male)}</MALES>
</GENDERS>
```